# What is wrong in that appscript [used to replace text]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to replace `1` with `Published` though appscript for Google spreadsheet.

Here is my code -

```
function SearchReplaceInFormula() {

  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AjCcE3eIeB3pdG5za09VSk92R3hMVFNfcV9vNHhfdHc");
var sheet = data.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var cell = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
cell.toString().replace("1", "Published");

}
```

Where is the problem actually?

Comment: @elclanrs: I'm not clear what you mean. Should I use /1/g instead of 1? Tried that but did not work! Any more suggestion?

Comment: @Zils Regular expressions aren't supposed to be quoted. Try that (`/1/g`) without quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use setValue () to update the cell, once you have read it and assign it to a variable there is no link anymore between the cell and the variable.
try

```
    var modcell=cell.toString().replace("1", "Published");
    sheet.getRange.('A1').setValue (mod cell);
```

Comment: Thank! But i'm getting this error now- TypeError: function getRange() {/* */} is not an XML object.

Comment: are you sure you did type it correctly ? you shouldn't use braces but parenthesis. Also it may happen when you type 2 dots before a method call...

Comment: Great it worked! There was an extra dot after getRange! Thanks!